# Фее-ед или фе-еед

Tags: перенос

В русском языке нельзя делать так, чтобы подряд шли три согласные, однако можно делать так, если по правилам это делать, чтобы подряд шли три гласные, напр.: *фея + есть – фееед.*

Мой вопрос таки-с: как мы такие слова на слоги должны разделять? Я думаю, что так как мы слова, которые состоят из нескольких слов и имеют соединительную гласную, делим на слоги посредством того, что их на слоги разъединяем после соед. гл., то нам нужно так делать и в этом случае. Следовательно, нужно разъединять как *фее-ед,* а не как *фе-еед.* Правда ли то, что я написал-таки?

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить. Ваш вопрос связан именно с разделением на слоги или переносом слова по слогам? Если как написано у вас, то слово "фееед" делится на три слога: *фе-е-ед*.

Comment: А вы уверены? При разделении на слоги вроде бы учитывается не только чистая фонетика, но и морфемный состав.

Comment: Деление на слоги – вещь неоднозначная, это кто, как и где договорится (тоже темная школа).   Иногда СЕРЬЕЗНО об этом спорить просто не хочется. Вот, например, информация из ресурса  :https://kpfu.ru/docs/F1274724716/Kamalova.L.A.Lekciya._.6..Fonetika.pdf  Вот и получается: каков вопрос, таков и ответ...

Comment: @Sharon Пока некогда здесь находиться и переходить по ссылке. Я знаю, что по слогам делят по-разному, то есть согласные относят либо влево, либо вправо, и учитывают морфемы. Но в моём миропонимании есть чёткая картина: слог всегда включает гласную и количество слогов равно количеству гласных. *Длин - но - ше - е - е*.

Comment: "Нам не дано предугадать. как слово наше отзовется..." Кстати, как разделить по слогам: пре-ду-га-дать? Правильно? Впрочем, ваша партия сильнее... Всем почему-то нравится именно фонетический принцип деления на слоги)) Даже соединительная гласная выделяется как отдельный слог. А в слове пти-це-ед она присоединена вроде бы к первому корню. Фонетика правит всем...

Comment: @Sharon  Ну да, так мелодичнее. Но мне само деление на слоги не очень интересно, для практических целей мне важно, как переносить. Рекомендуют не делить приставку или корень, но  правила сейчас не строгие, допускаются такие переносы:  *по-дбить, подб-росить, прис-лать, отс-транить и отст-ранить*. Это с Грамоты, видели, наверное.

Comment: Я тоже не интересуюсь. Ссылку я вам дала, чтобы вы ее открыли – и быстро закрыли... Я (для общего развития) в свое время записала для себя такую информацию: 1. Слог определяется как произносительный квант речи. Он не выражает смысловых связей звуков, как морфемы,  а  характеризуется АКУСТИЧЕСКОЙ ИЛИ АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННОЙ слитностью звуков при их произношении. 
2. По одной теории, слог – это один гласный звук или несколько звуков, которые произносятся ОДНИМ ТОЛЧКОМ выдыхаемого воздуха (лод-ка). По другой теории, слоги строятся по принципу ВОСХОДЯЩЕЙ ЗВУЧНОСТИ (ло-дка).

Comment: А у школьников свои правила переноса, Очень трудные (недавно их учебники для 3-го класса читала, ничего не запоминается). Им вроде бы от корня не разрешают одну гласную отрывать.

Comment: @Sharon Да, спасибо, посмотрел.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кто у нас птице-ед, тот, наверное, и фее-ед. Поэтому правильно: ***фее-ед.***
("Записки юного натуралиста")

Answer (score 1):

Фееед делится на 3 слога, что понятно, если сделать фонетическую транскрипцию -
**[ф'э-jэ-jэт]**.